# Probability distribution function for singular value sum of Gaussian random matrix

Tags: pr.probability, linear-algebra, st.statistics, traces

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be an $N \times N$ random matrix with IID Gaussian entries. They can be standard normal, but $N$ is *not* large: that is $N$ $<$ 6, typically. Call its singular value decomposition (SVD):

$\mathbf{X}$ $=$ $\mathbf{U} \mathbf{S} \mathbf{V}^{\text{T}}$,

where $s_{k}$ is singular value $k$. What's the probability distribution function for $\text{trace}\left(\mathbf{S}\right)$?

Here is my simple minded approach: the trace of the related matrix product $\text{trace}\left(\mathbf{S}^{\text{T}} \mathbf{S}\right)$ is equivalent to the Frobenius norm of $\mathbf{X}$, which is distributed as a $\chi^{2}$:

$$\text{trace}\left(\mathbf{S}^{\text{T}} \mathbf{S}\right) = \| \mathbf{X} \|_{F}^{2} = \sum_{k=1}^{N} X_{k k}^{2} \sim \chi_{N\cdot N}^{2}.$$

I initially guessed $\text{trace}\left(\mathbf{S}\right)$ was a sum of $N^{2}$ $\chi$ random variables (no square) by assuming Cochran's theorem. Monte Carlo runs seemed to support this assumption.

That said, Cochran's theorem does not seem to apply, since I cannot say that $s_{k}$ is normally distributed. I am trying to get the solution without the Eigenvalue distribution function, which appears difficult to use. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there's hope for a simple closed form expression at finite $N$.

Comment: The joint distribution of singular values is explicitly known, and can be written in terms of orthogonal (Laguere) polynomials; see Forrester's book on random matrices for a good reference with details. For $N<6$ you can in principle integrate this. Tedious, but doable..

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but may we assume that the eigenvalues (or singular values in my case) are independent? Computing the 2nd moment of the joint distribution will give that, but again, appears quite formidable. Assuming independence, then the sum of singular values could be computed from the characteristic function method, correct?

Comment: As answered by Carlo in your new questions, they are not independent. Just look up joint distribution of eigenvalues for Wishart matrices, for example in Forrester's book

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your comments. Sounds like it sufficiently complicated!

Comment: I looked a bit into the the distribution of $\mathrm{trace(S)}$. More specifically, the expected value of $\frac1N\mathrm{trace(S)}$ as a function of $N$. The behavior of this sequence appears to be difficult to understand, and surprisingly different for the real and complex valued model (I wrote a blog post about this: http://afonsobandeira.wordpress.com/2013/11/01/a-conjecture-on-the-singular-values-of-a-gaussian-matrix/ )